# Get price of a magento product with options

Tags: magento

I would like to get the price of a product without adding it into the cart, I have an array like

```
(option_id => Option_value,option_id => Option_value)
```

I need to get the price of the product with those options, I try using "addCustomOption" like

```
 $product->addCustomOption($option->getCode(), $option->getValue());
```

but when I use

```
$product->getFinalPrice()
```

It is still returning the original price.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem, discovering that "Final Price" is calculated when you call "Mage::getModel('catalog/product')", so if you change an option you have to reset the "Final Price" data to NULL, and then when you're calling

```
$product->getFinalPrice()
```

Magento will re-calculate the nice price